# As of 2020, what is the racial composition of the U.S. Senate?

Tags: united-states, senate

Inspired by the latest protests against racial discrimination: I'm wondering what the racial composition of the U.S. Senate as of 2020?

Comment: @BrianZ, exactly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2020, there are 3 African American senators (out of 100), two Democrats and one Republican.(In the census defined meaning of "African-American"):  Tim Scott (R), Cory Booker (D) and Kamala Harris (D).

Moreover there are 5 Hispanic/Latino senators,  and there are 3 with an Asian heritage, including Kamala Harris, who has both African and Indian ancestry. No current senators have substantial Native American ancestry.

In the House of Representatives (with 435 members), there are also 54 African American Representatives and 17 Representatives with a Asian or Pacific Islander heritage and four Representatives with a Native American ancestry.

All this information, and more is found in [Membership of the 116th Congress: A Profile](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R45583.pdf) published by the Congressional Research Service (a nonpartisan shared staff to congressional committees and Members of Congress)

Comment: So, overwhelming majority are white men and women?

Comment: @user2501323 Correct, especially white men as [there are currently only 26 women senators](https://www.senate.gov/senators/ListofWomenSenators.htm).

Comment: @BrianZ Not only white men but probably also old.  But then a senator is probably somebody where you would expect a bit of age.